# Jmeter 5.2.1 Cannot load JDBC drivers, Works fine in Jmeter 5.1.1

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

[JDBC Connection Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpCIL.png)

Tests with database connections that work in Jmeter 5.1.1 do not currently work with Jmeter 5.2.1

Comment: what error do you get? it should be in View Results Tree and jmeter.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter doesn't come with any [JDBC Drivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) included, as per [1.2.5 JDBC Driver](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_jdbc) documentation chapter:

> You will need to add your database vendor's JDBC driver to the [classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) if you want to do JDBC testing. Make sure the file is a jar file, not a zip.

1. Copy `postgresql-xx.x.x.xxx.jar` file from the "lib" folder of your JMeter 5.1.1 installation to the "lib" folder of JMeter 5.2.1. If you don't have access to the previous JMeter installation anymore - get the appropriate driver from [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Downloads page](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. That's it, you should be able to successfully execute your request now

Just in case check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter/) article

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.  All fixed now.